# M command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

Tentei instalar um modulo e encontrei algumas irregularidades. Gostaria de que se trata precisamente. Achei que fosse um conflito ente diretórios `/usr/bin/nodejs` e `usr/bin/npm`. Tentei instalar `nodejs-legacy` mas não resolveu.

[image: !]

Comment: Você tentou rodar este comando da pasta raiz do seu aplicativo? Aí parece que você está dentro da pasta node_modules. Tenta rodar na pasta do app e vê se o erro continua...
Tente atualizar o npm também: npm -g install npm@latest

Comment: @GabrielMarques tentei mas nao funcionou !!